# The output does not follow sequential order

Tags: java, output, java.util.scanner

The problem is that the output does not follow a certain order when printing the statements. It is supposed to print the statements one by one as the user inputs the answer to the question. For example, it outputs the first statement individually but as soon as the user hits 'enter' it outputs the next 2 statements at once.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
    int rollNumber;
    int scoreOne;
    int scoreTwo;

    public Student(String n, int a, int rN, int s1, int s2) {
        name =n;
        age =a;
        rollNumber =rN;
        scoreOne = s1;
        scoreTwo = s2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String information;
        information = name + " is " + "years old." + name + "roll number is" + rollNumber + "." + name + "average is" + (scoreOne+scoreTwo)/2;
        return information;
    }
}

public class StudentMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        s.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEnter age: ");
        s.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEnter Roll Number: ");
        s.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEnter Score One: ");
        s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Score Two: ");
        s.nextLine();


        Student information = new Student(s.nextLine(), s.nextInt(), s.nextInt(), s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());

        System.out.print(information.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `BufferedReader` for such applications

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear buffer in scanner before accepting a string input so just write

```
s.nextLine();
before

String s=s.nextLine();
```

and it shall work.It also seems to me that you are creating an information object which has the inputted values from the user.Then you must store the values simultaneously from the user and then accept it and then pass theses stored values to create the information object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String nm=s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter age: ");
        String age=s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Roll Number: ");
        String rn=s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Score One: ");
        String one=s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Score Two: ");
        String two=s.nextLine();


        Student information = new Student(nm, Integer.parseInt(age),Integer.parseInt(rn) , Integer.parseInt(one), Integer.parseInt(two));

        System.out.print(information.toString());
    }
```

Comment: @HetParikh ,added the code,see if it serves your purpose